# Number Operator on the Product State of Identical Bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, eigenvalue, bosons, identical-particles

Suppose that we have a single photon (or any elementary boson) with the state $$\Phi_{1} = |n\rangle.$$
Suppose also that there is a two-particle system whose state is given by $$\Phi_{2} = |n\rangle_{1}|n\rangle_{2}.$$

How exactly does the number operator $\hat{N}$ act on $\Phi_{1}$ and $\Phi_{2}$, respectively?

Also, is it right to think that the eigenvalue of the operator $|n\rangle\langle n|$ acted on $|n\rangle$ and the egenvalue of the operator $|n\rangle\langle n| \otimes |n\rangle\langle n|$ on $|n\rangle_{1}|n\rangle_{2}$ are both $1$?

Fundametnally, all I need to know is if there is any operator (doesn't have to be Hermitian) of which eigenvalue for $\Phi_{1}$ is different from its eigenvalue for $\Phi_{2}$.

Thanks!

Comment: how is your number operator defined?  it is $\hat N=\hat N_1+\hat N_2$?

Comment: As I understand your question, one would have for $\Phi_1$ the number operator $\hat N_1$ so that $\hat N_1\Phi_1=n\Phi_1$.  On the other hand, for $\Phi_1$ the number operators would be $\hat N=\hat N_1+\hat N_2$ so that $\hat N\Phi_2=(n+n)\Phi_2=2\Phi_2$ but is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I think what you're saying is right. That's basically what the answer below is saying, right?

Answer (score 3):

If $|n\rangle$ lives in the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, then $|n_1\rangle \otimes |n_2\rangle$ lives in the composite Hilbert space $\mathcal H \otimes \mathcal H$.

The number operator which acts on $|n\rangle$ is different from the number operator which acts on $|n_1\rangle\otimes |n_2\rangle$.  The former is an operator which acts on an element of $\mathcal H$, while the latter is an operator which acts on an element of $\mathcal H \otimes \mathcal H$.

A sensible definition of the composite number operator would be

$$\hat N_2 = \hat N \otimes \hat I + \hat I \otimes \hat N$$

where $\hat N$ and $\hat I$ are the number operator and identity operator which act on $\mathcal H$.  If this operator acts on your product state, it returns

$$\hat N_2 \big(|n_1\rangle\otimes |n_2\rangle \big) = \hat N\otimes \hat I \big(|n_1\rangle\otimes |n_2\rangle\big) + \hat I \otimes \hat N\big(|n_1\rangle \otimes |n_2\rangle\big)$$
$$ = n_1\big(|n_1\rangle\otimes |n_2\rangle\big) + n_2 \big(|n_1\rangle\otimes|n_2\rangle\big) = (n_1+n_2)\big(|n_1\rangle\otimes |n_2\rangle\big)$$

Comment: Thanks, that totally makes sense! Now, suppose you don't know how many particles there are in your system, and you would like to find that out. Is there any version of the number operator that would correspond to something you can physically do to figure out the number of particles in your system?

Comment: @Anti-Tachyon If you want to treat systems with an undetermined number of particles, then you need to turn to turn to many-body quantum mechanics / quantum field theory, see e.g. [second quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization) and the [number operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_number_operator).  I'm not sure if that's what you mean, though.